# How to post the information of web form's submit button to the server in cocoa?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, forms, cocoa

Basically, I know how to post web form data using `NSURLConnection`. But the problem is there are 3 submit buttons in the web form, and when you click any one of them, the server will check the one which has been clicked. In iOS or cocoa, how am I gonna tell the server about this?

Here is the code of the form in the html:

```
<form name="myform" action="checkLogin.jsp" method="post" onSubmit="return checkSubmit();">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td height="38" width="80" class="login_txt">account：&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="200"><input type="text" class="editbox4" name="username" id="username" value="" size="20" maxlength="24"></td>
        <td width="240">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td height="35" class="login_txt">password： &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="password" class="editbox4" name="password" id="password" size="20" maxlength="24"  style="height: 25px;vertical-align: middle;"> <img src="public/images/luck.gif" width="19" height="18" style="vertical-align: bottom;"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td height="35" class="login_txt">ip：&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td><span class="login_txt">118.228.173.165</span><input type="hidden" name="ip" value="118.228.173.165"> </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td height="35" colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="connect" class="login_button" name="action"> <input type="submit" value="disconnect" class="login_button" name="action"> <input type="submit" value="manage" class="login_button" name="action"></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit inputs are a little bit special in a form.

As you may know, a browser always sends values for every input/textbox/anything in the form. Except for the submit buttons. It will only send the submit button that has been clicked.

For example, if you click on the `connect` button, the data sent will look like this:

```
username: hello
password: world
action: connect
```

Or, should you click on the disconnect button:

```
username: hello
password: world
action: disconnect
```

Thus, you can send the right action in your NSURLConnection to select the action that must be done by the server.